# php If statement inside html table wrong output

Tags: php, html

i need to use if statement inside my table
the value of the row is "Released" but i want to show Pending on my html table. how can i achieve it. this is my current code. what's wrong with my if statement?

```
 if (strlen($row['signed']) == "Released") {
                                    echo "Pending";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo $row['signed']; 
                                    }
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns the length of the argument, so it returns an integer. You're trying to compare an integer to a string, which always fails.

Comment: why you are using strlen function? try it with remove of strlen function.

Comment: First you read the use of [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: what do you expect from _strlen($row['signed'])_ ?

Answer (score 3):

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)   checks for string length. first check either  **signed** is set in the array  and then check if value is equal

```
 if (isset($row['signed']) && $row['signed'] == "Released") {
                                    echo "Pending";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo $row['signed']; 
                                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` returns the length of the argument, so it returns an integer. You can check if value is equals to the string which you want something like this:

```
if ($row['signed'] == "Released") {
   echo "Pending";
} else {
   echo "Released";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` is used to count the length of the string, to check if it matches `"Released"`, just use `==` to compare:

```
if ($row['signed'] == "Released") {
    echo "Pending";
} else {
    echo $row['signed']; 
}
```

To find out is `$row['signed']` is set, just use `isset()`:

```
if (isset($row['signed'])) {
    echo "Pending";
} else {
    echo $row['signed']; 
}
```

More information on `isset()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

More information on PHP operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($row['signed'] == "Released") {
   $value = "Pending";
} else {
   $value = "Released" 
}
```

And add `<?php echo $value; ?>` in your table